# Update Column With Incrementing Value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I currently have a table and let's say it has ~100 rows of data. One of the columns, "UserName", is currently null in 88 rows. The 12 rows with data looks like:

```
User1
User2
User3
User4
User5
User6
etc
```

I want to fill the rest of the 88 rows with User13, User14, etc... How do I update the rows to do this with the incrementing values?

Comment: Do you have id column in your table?

Comment: Yes, I have an Id column

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend an updatable CTE.  This is a bit tricky because you need to continue the numbering, but I think this works:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by (select null)) as seqnum,
             max(convert(int, stuff(username, 1, 4, ''))) over () as maxnum
      from t
     )
update toupdate
    set username = 'User' + convert(varchar(255), seqnum + maxnum)
    where username is null;
```

If you don't remind updating all the rows, you can use:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by case when username is not null then convert(int, stuff(username, 1, 4, '')) else 999999 end) as seqnum
      from t
     )
update toupdate
    set username = 'User' + convert(varchar(255), seqnum);
```

This should keep the existing ordering, but if there are gaps then this would eliminate them.

Comment: Hello Gordon, I'm getting the error:
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'sometexthere' to data type int.

Comment: So, the convert is not working because the size of the string is unknown. The 88 other rows have variable length strings. They are not "User<X>" just yet. They are null or random.

Comment: Hello Gordon, I got it to work, I just set it to 1, 30 for Stuff() that way it will cover everything. bad news is it did overwrite existing columns that had UserX. But I can just manually change 12 rows which is easier than 88. Thanks again

Comment: @GeorgeDaniel . . . If solving the problem with variable length strings is important, then ask *another* question.  That is solvable but the answer looks a bit different.

Answer (score 2):

Would something like this work:

```
;WITH UserTable
AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [user] DESC) as [row], 
           [UserName] as [user]
    FROM MyUserTable
) 
UPDATE u
SET 'User' + CAST(row AS varchar(10)) 
FROM UserTable u
WHERE u.[user] IS NULL
```